# Add scroll to inner div

Tags: html, web

I have:

```
<div id = "first" style="overflow-y:auto;">
<td colspan="2" style="background: #EFF4F8;"><div
id="second" style='height: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y: auto; width: 100%; min-width: 580px; line-height: 200%;'>
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;">${some_text}</pre>
</div></td>
</div>
```

if "some_text" width is larger than my screen so I have scroll on all screen, I want the scroll only for div ="second" or for my pre tag. The problem is that I can't change div="first", I have to use it as is. Can you help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have a `td` tag outside of a table?!

Comment: You have serious problems with your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup seems wrong, but this should be your solution. Let me know how it turns out and I will update the answer to your needs. And use CSS:

**CSS**

```
#first {
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#second {
    height: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%; /* This might still mess up the overflows of parent- and child-tags in different browsers */
    min-width: 580px; /* This does not work well in all browsers */
    line-height: 200%;
}

#second pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="background: #EFF4F8;">
                    <div id="second">
                        <pre>${some_text}</pre>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to scroll across the width, that is a horizontal scrollbar.
You should be adding overflow-x